# List s3 files within folder lists only first folder files

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 bucket `bucket1` and a folder inside it as `test1`. There are a bunch of folders in that `test1` folder `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`. Each `folderx` contains bunch of files. I want to list all files in all folders. So list folder1's files and then folder2's files and so on.

```
s3_bucket --> test1 
                   ---> folder1
                               --->file1
                               --->file2
                   ---> folder2
                               --->file1
                               --->file2
                   ---> folder3
                               --->file1
                               --->file2
```

However with my code, it just lists folder1's files. Could someone please verify my code?

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=s3_path)

for file in resp['Contents']:
     key = file['Key']
     print key
```

PAGINATION: which doesn't iterate over folder2. folder1 has 1000 files.

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    kwargs = {'Bucket': s3_bucket}

    while True:
        resp = s3.list_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=s3_path)
        try:
            contents = resp['Contents']
            print(len(contents))
        except KeyError:
            return
        for file in contents:
            key = file['Key']

        try:
            kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
        except KeyError:
            break
```

Comment: working perfectly for me. please check if Prefix is proper or not

Comment: @anand can you send me the prefix you are using for my case?

Comment: Maybe you are getting a paginated response, and there are more to retrieve using `ContinuationToken`?

Comment: @Atihska the prefix is `test1/` if you want everything in "test1".  You may also need a paginator.  https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html

Comment: @dmulter You are right. it lists 1000 items. What is ContinuationToken. Is this required just for printing to console or in order to actually process the data beyond 1000?

Comment: @Michael You are right. it lists 1000 items

Comment: So folder1 contains 1000 files itself. I tried pagination but it doesn't continue to the next folder. Please check my edits for code I used.

Comment: @Atihska I didn't use any `prefix`. try without prefix once.

Comment: Now this is turning into another question on pagination. Please read the docs on [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and the [examples](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#examples). It is very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all @dmulter @Michael @anand for all your suggestions and guidance.

This worked where s3 path is the key (in unix terms, folder path excluding bucket).

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket)

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_path):
    key = obj.key
```